# How to stop a IIS Website completely from powershell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, iis

I'm trying to write a backup plan with powershell that archives the website root directory and send it to sftp server. The problem is that even when I stop the website with either of these two commands

```
Stop-WebSite "website"
Stop-IISSite -Name "website"
```

as the compression wants to start it throws an error as following

> ZipArchiveHelper : The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub...\www\AutoMapper.dll' because
> it is being used by another process.
> At
> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:697
> char:30

When I stop the website from IIS manager the code works fine, so is there any way to stop a website completely from Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to stop the App Pool of the Website. So it will not load process.

Step will be,
1.Stop IIS Website.
2.Stop IIS Website App Pool.
3.Copy Files

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have taught about this solution but starting application pools some times give error and i don't want my website to be stopped and not started in the middle of night so that employee gets angry